# Cakephp 3 : How to update migration file?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have create my database migration file by below command

```
bin/cake bake migration_snapshot Initial
```

after that I have update a table with add a new field like

```
->addColumn('role', 'string', [
                'default' => null,
                'limit' => 20,
                'null' => true,
])
```

Then I have used

```
bin/cake migrations migrate
```

command windows given a message "All done" 
But nothing has been updated ! 
How can I update my migration file ?

Comment: What does "_I have updated a table_" mean? Have you modified the initial migration snapshot file? Or maybe created a new migration file? Also where do you apply the migration? On an already existing database? On a side note, just because you're writing it always like that, it's "_below_", not "[_bellow_](https://www.google.com/search?q=bellow&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X)".

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Yes I have initiated snapshot file, then I have just add a new field in initial page. Then I have used 

bin/cake migration migrated 

But new field hasn't updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the initial shapshot on the database the snapshot was created from, won't have any effect of course, as that snapshot will automatically be marked as migrated (by adding an appropriate entry to the version history table, which is by default named `phinxlog`).

So when you try to apply that migration on the database it was created from, it will not be applied, as it matches the current version. If you would use a new/empty database, then the initial migration would be applied.

To apply changes you have to create a new migration file, either manually, or by using bake, and then apply that migration. Quick example:

```
bin/cake bake migration AddRoleToUsers role:string
bin/cake migrations migrate
```

This will create a new migration that adds a `role` column (which will by default have a length of `255`), apply it, and again mark the migration as migrated by adding the version to the before metioned version history table.

Comment: Is it possible to create this change in initial.php page ? For example manually if I add role field intial.php page , can I update initial.php page ?

Comment: @AlimonKarim That's not how migrations are supposed to be used, so you shouldn't even try it! As mentioned, the initial snapshot will only be applied on new/empty databases.

Comment: ok I understand thank you. But I have last question don't mind please. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752128/cakephp-3-how-to-avoid-migrated-file-by-cake-command

Answer (score 0):

Increment the number on the name of the migrations file and you can re-run it. I use this quite a lot before I finalize an individual migration file.